# Storing shortest path route - QGIS 3.22.9

Tags: qgis, route, shortest-path

I used the shortest path tool in QGIS 3.22 to find the shortest route from the node "1000" to node "1004" in my project. The result is shown in red around my road layers (links) in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to store somewhere or export in Excel the route (links crossed in the right order, i.e. providing a list of the successive `Link_ID` crossed using their `Link_ID` in red on the pic: 1,2,4,3) ?

I tried but could not find using QGIS tools. The end objective is to calculate traffic along roads (links) and displaying them as a traffic map.

Comment: What do you mean to "store the route"? You can simply export/save the line geometry, e.g. as Geopackage or Shapefile. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I mean obtaining the list of Links (roads) which have been crossed, in the right order. So here, I would like to have the list of links crossed in order to compute the shortest path. the idea is to have this list for all possible OD combinations (nodes) on a map, and then sum some attributes such as traffic figures to be displayed on a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this expression to get a comma separated list of `LinkID` values from the layer called `network`:

```
array_to_string (overlay_contains ('network', LinkID))
```

*The expression, used here for visualization purpose as a dynamic label:*
[image]

Create a new field with Field calculator, copy the value from there and paste it to Excel or wherever you need the values. To get each value on a new row, add `,delimiter:= '\n'` at the end of the expression above, before the last closing bracket `)`

[image]

---

Edit: in my case, the segments are ordered in the correct way. If this is not the case, as in the test data you shared, the approach is a bit more complex. The first line of the expression creates a variable with the name of your `test` layer - rename it accordingly (see below for explanation):

```
with_variable ('ly', 'test', -- replace here: name of your network layer
array_to_string(  -- step 8
    array_foreach (
        array_sort (  -- step 5
            array_foreach (
                overlay_contains (@ly, $id),  -- step 1
                line_locate_point (  -- step 3
                    $geometry, 
                    centroid (geometry (get_feature_by_id (@ly,@element))) --step 2
                ) || ',' || @element  -- step 4
            )
        ), 
        attribute (  -- step 7
            get_feature_by_id (
                @ly,
                regexp_replace (@element,'(.*,)','')  -- step 6
            ),
            'Link_ID'
        )
    )
))
```

[image]

Explanantion:

1. Create an array of all the feature ids (`$id`) for each segment that is covered by the shortest path, using `overlay_contains()`
2. Get the centroid of each covered segment with `centroid()`
3. Get the distance each centroid is away from the start point of the shortest, along the shortest path line with `line_locate_point()` and by converting the `$id` value from step 1 to the feature's geometry with `geometry()`
4. Add the features's id (the `$id` from the array in step 1) after this distance (concatenate with `||` and insert `','` as delimiter) by calling the `@element` inside an `array_foreach()` loop

   You get an array where each elements consist of two parts, separated by comma: `distance from start point,$id` (pseudocode)
5. Sort the array with `array_sort()`. Like this, the shortest distance (corresponding to the first covered segment) is at the beginning
6. Now get rid of the distance, keeping only the `$id`, the second part of each element in the array, using `regexp_replace()`
7. You have now the `$id` values in the order the segments are covered. If you want to get an attribute value instead, access it, based on the feature id (`$id`) with `attribute()`
8. Convert the array to a string with `array_to_string()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help makes me progress in the right direction, but it seems there is still a problem in the order of the links crossed. In my case, it seems the order of the Link_ID attribute compiled is "increasing" by default. Instead, I should have "1, 2, 4, 3" in this order. Instead, I have "1, 2, 3, 4". I do not know how you got the right order in your screenshot.

Comment: I got the correct order by default. Can you share sample data for testing?

Comment: I saved the two layers of interest here: https://we.tl/t-qZK3wyCcu5 . Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: See edited answer for that

Comment: Thanks for the edited and complex answer you provided. It works perfectly fine. I definitely need to strengthen my comprehension of the expression builder.